# Lua, using table of strings as keys to call values from different tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

**What I want**

```
ores = {"Bauxite", "Coal", "Hematite"}

properties={["Bauxite"]={name="Bauxite", density=1.2808},["Coal"]={name="Coal" , density=1.3465},["Quartz"]={name="Quartz" , density=2.6498},["Hematite"]={name="Hematite" , density=5.0398}}

system.print(properties.ores[1].name)
system.print(properties.ores[1].density)
```

**Should Output**

```
Bauxite
1.2808
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I select value from table based on function input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568202/can-i-select-value-from-table-based-on-function-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recurrent question regarding indexing tables by a value rather than by a constant string. You're currently using `((properties.ores)[1]).name`; this is not parsed as `properties.(ores[1]).name` as you seem to have expected. That's because `.` is always followed by an identifier - a constant string - which is used to index the table. `table.key` is just shorthand for `table["key"]` for keys matching `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`. If you want to dynamically index a table with some expression, you have to use `table[expr]`.

To fix your code, simply do:

```lua
system.print(properties[ores[1]].name)
system.print(properties[ores[1]].density)
```